# DateTimeOffset Sample in SQL 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a doubt related to using `datetimeoffset` in SQL server 2008 r2.

Suppose I have a web application, the db server in Spain and the client is in Canada. I don't know the time zone between Spain and Canada but suppose its 5 hours more in Spain.
So user in Canada wants to add a new Employee at 23:00 PM, when clicks save, it calls a stored procedure that inside call the function `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` to fill the column `CreatedDate` that has a datatype `datetimeoffset(7)`.

In this case, what will be the datetime saved in the database? and How should I do to show the right datetime to the user in Canada that wants to check the `CreatedDate`? Is there any good example to check this?

Answer (score 14):

According to MSDN:

> The data is stored in the database and processed, compared, sorted, and indexed in the server as in UTC. The time zone offset will be preserved in the database for retrieval.

In your example, the data will be stored in a binary format that can be translated to `14 Nov 2013 23:00 -5:00`, which means the date and time that is local plus the time offset of -5 hours to UTC (let's suppose this is the offset for Canada).

When you store this type of value, you have to provide the offset yourself, the system doesn't do it automatically.

Because the data is stored as UTC time, it makes comparison, sorting, etc. of data easy, while you can always retrieve the original time offset.

You should generally store client's local time with offset when storing information about events that need to be compared across time zones.

More on `datetimeoffset` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx).

---

Example

Create a table and insert data

```
create table dto (dto datetimeoffset(7))

insert into dto values (GETDATE()) -- inserts date and time with 0 offset
insert into dto values (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) -- current date time and offset
insert into dto values ('20131114 08:54:00 +10:00') -- manual way
```

When I select the data, I get

```
2013-11-14 07:56:17.2300000 +00:00 -- current time, no offset so useless in this case
2013-11-14 07:56:17.2338125 +11:00 -- current time with my local offset (in Australia)
2013-11-14 08:54:00.0000000 +10:00 -- manually inserted data
```

Comment: Can I see and example please?

Comment: Updated the answer with an example

Comment: ok I wasn't so clear, in my example the datetime saved on the database will be the one in Spain but how can I show the record with the datetime in Canada when the user wants to see the record?

Comment: Do you need to do it in sql? It's easier in the code on the client as you can express datetimeoffset from the db as local time easily. If you have to do it in Sql, it's more complex as the query always run on the server.

Comment: Ok but how can I show the datetime in Canada with the offset that corresponds to that Country if in the database is saved with the local time?

Comment: No, the time in the database is saved as **UTC time** and **additionally** offset is saved - this is written above. That allows you to convert that to any other time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store the UTC date in your DB

```
Select GetUTCDate()
```

For Example, DB Server is in Spain and a client in CANADA
adds a new Employee Joining date in System. (UTC Date)  **`14 Nov 2013 23:00`**

so if you want to show the right DateTime to the user in Canada you need to add/subtract your current time zone offset like if in Canada it's UTC-4 so

```
Select Cast('14 Nov 2013 23:00' as Datetime) as [UTC TIME]
Select DateAdd(hour,+2,Cast('14 Nov 2013 23:00' as Datetime))  as [Time In Spain]
Select DateAdd(hour,-4,Cast('14 Nov 2013 23:00' as Datetime))  as [Time In Canada]
```

Result

```
14 Nov 2013 23:00
15 Nov 2013 01:00
14 Nov 2013 19:00
```

you can make some function to do this...